# What is the better way to string format a double quote if the element inside the quote is a variable?

Tags: c#, json, double-quotes

I have made a code like this:

```
TextWriter tw = File.CreateText(@"D:\output.txt");

tw.Write(@"{""lon"":" + grid.point[0].ToString("###.####") + ",");
tw.Write(@"""latt"":" + grid.point[1].ToString("###.####") + ",");

char c = '"';
////improve the last line pls 
tw.Write(@"""color"":" + c.ToString() + "#" + grid.Color.ToString("X").Substring(2) + c.ToString() + "},\n");
```

With the above code, I had successfully made a JSON format look like below:

```
{"lon":121,"latt":40.5025,"color":"#3EC1FF"},
```

**Now My question is:**
How to improve the string format without using the `c.toString()`?

Comment: 'improve ' in what way? readability?

Comment: also consoder stringBuilder.AppendFormat() which add some perfomance

Comment: @BinsonEldhose How would using `StringBuilder` in this scenario improve performance?

Comment: @BinsonEldhose I see your answer, why would it improve performance? `StringBuilder` is only usually beneficial at doing lots of string concatenations within a large loop...

Comment: @DGibbs, i agree that,   all the answers for this post will work, but to need a better coding clarity i suggested String.Format(), then i thought, if he have 100 or more data to process, then stringbuilder usefull

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the format overload of the `Write` method e.g. [Write(String, Object[])](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b2t77weh%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Something like this:

```
tw.Write("\"color\":\"#{0}\"}},\n", grid.Color.ToString("X").Substring(2));
```

Comment: Since this is a json string you will also need to escape the curly braces `}`. I have updated my answer, you will need to use `}}` or `{{` to escape them.

Answer (score 0):

```
StringBuilder jsonBuilder=new StringBuilder();
 jsonBuilder.AppendFormat("{0}", "{");

 jsonBuilder.AppendFormat("\"Lat\":{0:0.000},", 584.25689);
 jsonBuilder.AppendFormat("\"Lon\":{0:0.000},", 784.25689);


 jsonBuilder.AppendFormat("Color:{0}","\"#3EC1FF\"");
 jsonBuilder.AppendFormat("{0}", "}");

  string json = jsonBuilder.ToString();
```

Comment: Use  using System.Text